# fullBaseUrl not properly works with AuthComponent

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.7

Recenty I've moved my application to subdirectory so I've configured fullBaseUrl like this:

```
Configure::write('App.fullBaseUrl', 'https://example.com/subdirectory');
```

Nothing more changed in app and it all works perfect, except one thing - accessing unauthorized locations.

I've defined like this:

```
$this->Auth->loginAction = ['controller' => 'app_users', 'action' => 'login', 'admin' => false];
$this->Auth->loginRedirect = ['controller' => 'dashboard', 'action' => 'index', 'admin' => false];
$this->Auth->logoutRedirect = ['controller' => 'app_users', 'action' => 'login', 'admin' => false];
$this->Auth->unauthorizedRedirect = ['controller' => 'dashboard', 'action' => 'index', 'admin' => false];
```

Thus this logged users when try to access unauthorized action are redirected to their's dashboard, but users that are not logged in should be redirected to login form.

But after moving app to subdirectory and defining fullBaseUrl for unauthorized locations I'm getting redirect like this:

```
https://example.com/subdirectory/subdirectory/app_users/login
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug that was recently [fixed](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/7239). It will be available in the next bugfix release for 2.7 series. If you need it right away use the 2.7 git branch.

Comment: 2.7.3 has been just released (http://cakephp.org/changelogs/2.7.3), but probably this fix has been forgotten :(

Comment: Reading the issue again, your problem might be related to value you have set for 'App.fullBaseUrl'. Set it to only the domain, don't include subdirectory. Set `App.baseUrl` to '/subdomain/'.

Comment: Then I can't use mod_rewrite and so on as I'm properly understand the docs?

Comment: You can use `App.baseUrl` with mod_rewrite.

Comment: It doesn't work for me when I set `App.baseUrl` to `/subdirectory/` - all of the assets are broken then.